# Can we add a new variable via geom_point to geom_boxplot in GGPLOT?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a geom_point to a boxplot.  The boxplot displays the appropriate data for the `Total`, but I want add the `Mkt_Avg` to show how the average compares to the percentiles created by the boxplot.  I have tried the code below, but it doesn't work (geom_point).  Any thoughts on how to do this?  Do I need to add a new aes()?  Any help is appreciated.

```
tbl <- tribble(
  ~Dept ,  ~Total, ~Mkt_Avg,
  'a',     '15000', '9500',
  'a',     '6000', '9500',
  'a',     '7200', '9500',
  'a',     '7300', '9500',
  'a',     '6500', '9500',
  'a',     '2700', '9500',
  'c',     '8100', '7950',
  'c',     '20000', '14500',
  'c',     '15000', '14500',
  'c',     '9200', '6500',
  'd',     '11500', '6500',
  'd',     '1600', '3875',
  
  
)

tbl <- tbl %>%
  mutate(Total = as.numeric(Total),
         Mkt_Avg = as.numeric(Mkt_Avg)) %>%
  mutate(Dept = as_factor(Dept)) %>%
  mutate(Dept = Dept %>% fct_reorder(Total))

tbl %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Dept, Total)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_point(Mkt_Avg, color = "blue")
```

Comment: you need that inside `aes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be inside `aes` and the `coord_flip` can be afterwards

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
tbl %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Dept, Total)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(y = Mkt_Avg), color = "blue") +
  coord_flip()
```

-output

[image]